# WCF with a MVC.NET Endpoint - No parameters being passed through?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Think I might just be doing something wrong here, but I've been persisting and searching for a day or two now and I just can't figure this out.

I've got a re-usable WCF project within my solution, and a solution-specific MVC.NET project along side it.

Solution: -

- MVC.NET Project
- Class Library
- WCF Project

The WCF Test Client gets the expected results. However when trying to call the WCF services through the enpoints set up in the MVC Project I'm having some issues. If no parameters are passed through from the user, it works fine. However when trying to pass parameters to the webservice, none seem to be available inside the .svc file.

My endpoint code:

```
public override void RegisterArea( AreaRegistrationContext context ) {

    context.Routes.Add( new ServiceRoute( "Api/SOAP/Log", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof( Log ) ) );
    context.Routes.Add( new ServiceRoute( "Api/SOAP/Report", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof( Report ) ) );

    context.Routes.Add( new ServiceRoute( "Api/Rest/Log", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof( Log ) ) );
    context.Routes.Add( new ServiceRoute( "Api/Rest/Report", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof( Report ) ) );

}
```

A Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILog {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Search?systemName={systemName}&searchType={searchType}&query={query}&resultCount={resultCount}&ipAddress={ipAddress}")]
    SearchResult Search( string systemName, string searchType, string query, string resultCount, string ipAddress );

}
```

And a svc Service:

public class Log : ILog {

```
public void Search( string systemName, string searchType, string query, string resultCount, string ipAddress ) {

    LogSearch Manager = new LogSearch();
    Manager.ProcessWcfRequest( systemName, searchType, query, resultCount, ipAddress);

}
```

}

These params are obviously not getting through. I've also tried inspecting **System.Web.HttpContext.Current** and **WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters** at runtime, and these don't contain the params either.

I'm making the request using the following AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Api/Rest/Log/Search",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { systemName : "test", searchType : "test", query : "test", resultCount : "test", ipAddress : "test" },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

So to re-iterate, the request is going through and I can hit breakpoints in my Service, meaning any service methods which require no params are fine, however for those that do require params, none are passed.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I've managed to solve this and get my parameters through, however the situation isn't ideal really. If anyone has a better approach, please let me know.

To solve this, I ended up having to attach a Stream object to each method. See below:

Contract:

```
void Search( string systemName, string searchType, string query, string resultCount, string ipAddress, Stream postData );
```

Service:

```
public void Search( string systemName, string searchType, string query, string resultCount, string ipAddress, Stream postData ) {
```

Then within the service, I can do this:

```
NameValueCollection MyParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( new StreamReader( postData ).ReadToEnd() );

if( MyParams[ "systemName" ] != null && MyParams[ "systemName" ].Length > 0 ) {
    systemName = MyParams[ "systemName" ];
}

if( MyParams[ "searchType" ] != null && MyParams[ "searchType" ].Length > 0 ) {
    searchType = MyParams[ "searchType" ];
}

if( MyParams[ "query" ] != null && MyParams[ "query" ].Length > 0 ) {
    query = MyParams[ "query" ];
}

if( MyParams[ "resultCount" ] != null && MyParams[ "resultCount" ].Length > 0 ) {
    resultCount = MyParams[ "resultCount" ];
}

if( MyParams[ "ipAddress" ] != null && MyParams[ "ipAddress" ].Length > 0 ) {
    ipAddress = MyParams[ "ipAddress" ];
}
```

This gives me the desired results, and means any GET params will be overwritten by any POST params, however it's a bit of a long winded way of accomplishing what should be a rather simple exercise.

I feel there is a better way, so if anyone could suggest one I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
data: JSON.stringify ({ systemName : "test", searchType : "test", query : "test", resultCount : "test", ipAddress : "test" }),
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Product> data = GetData(selectedCategory);
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

As i see you need to return json data.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. This change didn't make any difference for me. Is there anything else you could recommend?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me on this. The problem isn't actually returning the data, but getting the values of systemName, searchType, query etc inside my service. At the moment they all come up as null.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue when calling a webservice method via reporting services in the past - I know this is a different scenario, but the solution might be the same.

After a couple of days of fighting with it, I found that the issue was caused by a trailing forward slash in the namespace of the webservice:

```
http://tempuri.org/
```

removing the trailing slash sorted the issue for me

```
http://tempuri.org
```

Like I said, mine was a different scenario, but the same symptom - might be worth a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help in my case, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
 UriTemplate = "Search?systemName={systemName}&searchType={searchType}&query={query}&resultCount={resultCount}&ipAddress={ipAddress}")]
```

According to this attribute, all your parameters are supposed to be passed by GET.

Your ajax request URL should be "/Api/Rest/Log/Search?systemName=aaaaa&searchType=bbbb&query=cccc&resultCount=ddddd&ipAddress=eeeee"

So all you need change here is change your client js. Instead of using Post json, use GET passing params instead.

if your attempt is to using POST here then define your service contract in this way.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Search", <== CHANGE HERE 
     Method = "POST", 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,   <== ADD THIS HERE TO YOUR CODE 
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json <== ADD THIS HERE TO YOUR CODE )]
   SearchResult Search( string systemName, string searchType, string query, string resultCount.....)
```

Comment: Hi ValidfroM, thanks for the reply. Yes I understand this, and passing them all through as GET params works fine. However a stipulation from the client is that the API has to be accessible by both GET and POST. On many of the clients that plug into it, I'm not part of the front-end projects. Sorry, I should of stated this in my question.

Comment: @RickyS so you mean you want these params passed by both GET and POST?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I can't hard-code the response and request formats to JSON, and without those the service becomes inaccessible via the endpoint. Thanks though.